# How to install firebase pods for Specifically to Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3

I tried lot and searched Firebase documents. But I can't find any document to find Firebase pods specifically to Swift 3.0. Here I configured podfile for swift 3 & cleared pods, derived data. but it's always installing only latest version of pods and results error in pod file. I am using xcode 8 & swift 3 xcode project.

[image]

How can I install firebase for Swift 3.0? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install `Firebase` in your project, prerequisites are :

1. Install the following:

> Xcode 10.3 or later CocoaPods 1.4.0 or later

2. Make sure that your project meets these requirements:

> Your project must target iOS 8 or later.

[Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup)

Below `pod file` can be used to install the dependencies,

```
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '8.0'

install! 'cocoapods'

target 'Test' do
use_frameworks!
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end
```

Comment: So I should update source code... Thank you for your answer..

Answer (score 0):

step 1:

To add pod file

pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.1'

pod ‘Firebase/Core’

pod ‘Firebase/Database’

pod ‘Firebase/Auth’

step 2:

pod install

Comment: Thansk! But It's installing latest version only. Google doesn't have proper documentation. Even cocoapods doesn't consider about xcode version at all.. Really frustrated..